# Calculation inside datetime timedelta?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to understand the meaning of `datetime.timedelta`.

```
timedelta(days = 6 - d.weekday())
```

How does this work?

Comment: What is `d` in your example?

Comment: @BrenBarn -- Something with a `weekday` method.  It's probably reasonable to guess that its a `datetime.date` (or `datetime.datetime`) instance...

Answer (score 2):

[`datetime.date.weekday`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.weekday)<sup>1</sup> is a number.  `0` means the date is a Monday, `6` means the date is a Sunday.  If `d` represents a Saturday, then:

```
6 - d.weekday()  # 6 - 5 == 1
```

Generally, `6 - d.weekday()` is basically saying

> "Give me an integer that is the number of days until the Sunday after the date represented by `d`"

If you want to know how many days as a `timedelta` (e.g. so you can *calculate* the next Sunday), then you use `timedelta(days=6 - d.weekday())`

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>Remember that `datetime.datetime` inherits from `datetime.date`, so ... It has a `weekday` method defined exactly the same way</sup>

Comment: @skyrocker: One can avoid using hardcode integers like `6` by using `(MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY, FRIDAY, SATURDAY, SUNDAY) = range(7)` which would allow writing more readable code afterwards: i.e. `SUNDAY - d.weekday()`.

Comment: Thank you mgilson and martineau! Excellent explanation!